# Call component function from html view in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm stuck in -maybe- logic usage of Vue, I have a "list" component which get results from ajax, the problem appears when I want to add a search field, I have something like this:

search.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(result, index) in results">
      <h2>{{ result.name }}</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name : 'searchList',

    data() {
      return { results: [] }
    }

    created: function(){
      this.goSearch();
    },

    methods : {
      goSearch : function(){
        this.results = axios.get('/search');
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

This works like a charm, the point is that I want to add an input to search, I've made some research and I've found that the only way to get this is using another component, but I don't want to create another component just for an input, so I want to do something like:

index.html

```
<input type="text" v-model="goSearch">

<search-list></search-list>
```

But the problem that I'm facing is that Vue is returning an error:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "goSearch" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
```

I've also tried with `v-bind="goSearch"` but doesn't work either. Any ideas to accomplish this?

**UPDATE:**
I've created a button to call the function:

```
<button @click="goSearch"></button>
```

The function "goSearch" now tries to get the value from the text box, but also this doesn't work.

Comment: @Core972 I've read that, but as far as I know prop is only for child component to parent component, isn't it?

Comment: Your `created` and `methods` keys are out of the exported object. Do not you get a parse error?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting such error because you're using:

```
<input type="text" v-model="goSearch">
```

Here, the goSearch is `data` and this data is not found by vue. But you meant it to be a method. Vue doesn't work like that. You will not require to use `v-model` if you want to bind some method in it. But you will need to bind `v-on:input`

```
<input type="text" v-on:input="goSearch">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but also Vue returns the same error and adding a new one: 

[Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "input": got undefined

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `goSearch` method is defined inside the `searchList` component, anything outside of it doesn't know what it is (in this case, the input element), hence the warn.

A solution would be defining the method in the parent component (in this case, seems like it's index.html), so all children components can access it.

You would also have to store the `results` array inside the parent `data` and send it to the `searchList` component using [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props) together with the goSearch function, like so:

**search.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="(result, index) in results" v-bind:key="index">
            <h2>{{ result.title }}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'searchList',
    props: ['results'],
    created: function () {
      this.$emit('goSearch')
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Parent component:**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button v-on:click="goSearch">Get Random Post</button>
    <search-list
            v-on:goSearch="goSearch"
            v-bind:results="results"
    ></search-list>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import searchList from './components/searchList'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data () {
    return { results: [] }
  },
  components: {
    searchList
  },
  methods: {
    goSearch: function () {
      const postId = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1 + 1)) + 1
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + postId)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          this.results = [json]
        })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Keep in mind that if more than one component uses the property/method, you need to define it in a parent component, then you send that info to the children components using `props` and the children can trigger events of that parent using `emit`.

[image]

Also, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50720843/vuejs-send-data-to-modal-component/50722223#50722223).

Comment: This an excellent answer, but I can't unify the input and the results, because they have some html structure and put both together implies that I have to put all the HTML in vue template.  

Also, using $emit('goSearch'); returns an error: [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "ReferenceError: $emit is not defined", I think that you are talking about using two components, something that I don't want to do, but it seems that's a must.

Comment: How so? What happens?

Comment: I just update my comment. Sorry I hit enter prematurely.

Comment: May I ask, is everything wrapped inside the `export default` object?

Comment: Yes, it is. As a part of the component. In my app.js I just call it: Vue.component('search-list', require('./components/SearchList.vue')); 

But the <input> it's outside the component, of course.

Comment: I ask that because in the question, the methods and created are outside of the export default. Could you update your question reflecting those changes?

Comment: Sorry about that It was typo, I just update the code.

Comment: Check out the updated answer, I added a complete example of a `.vue` component with the button and the list, tested it locally and seems like it works, so you don't have to create another component just for that.

Comment: I'm sorry man, but the problem is that in your answer the <button> is within the <template>, I want to know if it's possible to use it on the view (index.html) part, because is the part where I have it.

Comment: You're right, my bad, I misunderstood your point. Check out the updated answer, seems like the issue you were having with `$emit` was because when using single file components ( `.vue` ) you have to use `this.$emit` .

Comment: Sorry for take so long in reply, but I think I'm not making myself clear, I just made a Codepen to explain what's going on: https://codepen.io/axd/pen/rKmMGy